# Filling missing values in pandas DataFrame for specific row value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to fill empty values for Age column based on passenger sex

I tried the following

```
if train_df[train_df['Sex'] == 'male']:
train_df["Age"] = train_df["Age"].fillna("10")
```

But, I get this error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/sebal/PycharmProjects/pythonProject4/main.py", line 21, in <module>
if train_df[train_df['Sex'] == 'male']:
File "C:\Users\sebal\PycharmProjects\pythonProject4\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", 
line 1441, in __nonzero__
raise ValueError(
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or 
a.all()
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

Your are checking the condition for the entire pandas serie instead of one value.

You can do something like this:

```
train_df.loc[train_df['Sex']=='male', 'Age'] = train_df.loc[train_df['Sex']=='male', 'Age'].fillna('10')
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `train_df[train_df['Sex'] == 'male']` doesn't return either True or False but an array of these as long as your dataframe.

To get either `True` or `False` returned you need to pass it just a single row out of the column. Currently, you are asking it which rows are Male and it is returning `[True, False, True, True, False]` (for example). The error occurs because how should this be evaluated? Is is True or False? It recommends so strategies to try and reduce this to a single value (`a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()`).

If you are trying to fill all the rows where `Sex` == Male` you should use the code in [@Anja S](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66091477/13876078)'s answer.